# Cauchy sequences...is my proof correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(x_n)_{n∈ℕ}$ and $(y_n)_{n∈ℕ}$ be Cauchy sequences of real numbers.
>
> Show, without using the Cauchy Criterion, that if $z_n=x_n+y_n$, then $(z_n)_{n∈ℕ}$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers.

Here's my attempt at a proof:

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be Cauchy sequences. Let $(z_n)$ be a sequence and let $z_n=x_n+y_n$.

Since $(x_n)$ and ($y_n)$ are Cauchy, $∃N∈ℕ$ such that $|x_n-x_m|<ε/2$ and $|y_n-y_m|<ε/2$ for $n,m≥N$.

Let $n,m≥N$ and let $z_n,z_m∈(z_n)$. Then,
$$|z_n-z_m|=|x_n-x_m|+|y_n-y_m| <ε/2+ε/2=ε.$$
Therefore, $|z_n-z_m|<ε$ for all $n,m≥N$ and hence, $(z_n)$ is a Cauchy sequence of real numbers.

Is this correct?
Any input is appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks OK the proof!

Comment: It's correct except for a minor detail. The triangle inequality results in a $\leq$ not a $=$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you have to correct is $$|z_n-z_m|=|(x_n-x_m)+(y_n-y_m)|\le|x_n-x_m|+|y_n-y_m| <ε/2+ε/2=ε.$$

Answer (score 0):

This proof looks correct to me.